# take value multiple checkbox ajax php for email

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Hello i have an contact form which user fill all details and he have multiple checkboxes and after he submit will send email will all values from fields and values from which checkboxes was checked, i did somethig with php ajax for formular and there is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function (e){
    $("#frmContact").on('submit',(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
         var myCheckboxes = new Array();
            $("input:checked").each(function() {
               data['myCheckboxes[]'].push($(this).val());
            });

        $("#mail-status").hide();
        $('#send-message').hide();
        $('#loader-icon').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "oferta.php",
            type: "POST",
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
            "den_org":$('input[name="den_org"]').val(),
            myCheckboxes:myCheckboxes,
            "pers_cont":$('input[name="pers_cont"]').val(),
            "localitate":$('input[name="localitate"]').val(),
            "email2":$('input[name="email2"]').val(),
            "tlf":$('input[name="tlf"]').val(),
            "nr_local":$('input[name="nr_local"]').val(),
            "nr_ang":$('input[name="nr_ang"]').val(),
            "dom_activ":$('input[name="dom_activ"]').val(),
            "alte":$('input[name="alte"]').val(),
            "g-recaptcha-response":$('textarea[id="g-recaptcha-response"]').val()},             
            success: function(response){
            $("#mail-status").show();
            $('#loader-icon').hide();
            if(response.type == "error") {
                $('#send-message').show();
                $("#mail-status").attr("class","error");                
            } else if(response.type == "message"){

                $('#send-message').hide();
                $("#mail-status").attr("class","success");                          
            }
            $("#mail-status").html(response.text);  
            },
            error: function(){} 
        });
    }));
});
```

I search on google even here and still can`t pass the value of checked boxes into file where i send email with php.
Here is the code for html:

```
<form id="frmContact" action="" method="POST" novalidate="novalidate">
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label >Certificari *</label>
        <ul class="c_list">
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="i11" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="ISO_9001"> ISO 9001</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="i11" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="ISO_140011"> ISO 14001</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="i11" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="ISO_45001"> ISO 45001</li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" class="i11" name="myCheckboxes[]" value="Other"> Other</li>
        </ul>
</div>
 </div>
```

And for php i have something like that:

```
<?php
  if($_POST)
  {
   include('config.php');

$den_org      = filter_var($_POST["den_org"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$pers_cont      = filter_var($_POST["pers_cont"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$localitate     = filter_var($_POST["localitate"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email2     = filter_var($_POST["email2"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$nr_ang     = filter_var($_POST["nr_ang"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$tlf     = filter_var($_POST["tlf"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$dom_activ     = filter_var($_POST["dom_activ"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$alte     = filter_var($_POST["alte"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$nr_local     = filter_var($_POST["nr_local"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$iso     = filter_var($_POST["myCheckboxes"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

if(empty($den_org)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>denumirea organizatiei</b>";     
}
if(empty($pers_cont)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>persoana de contact</b>";
}
if(empty($localitate)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>localitate</b>";
}   
// if(empty($email2)) {
//  $empty[] = "<b>email</b>";
// }
if(empty($nr_ang)) {
    $empty[] = "<b>numar angajati</b>";
}

if(!empty($empty)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => implode(", ",$empty) . ' Required!'));
    die($output);
}

// if(!filter_var($email2, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
//     $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>'.$email2.'</b> is an invalid Email, please correct it.'));
//  die($output);
// }

//reCAPTCHA validation
if (isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {

    require('component/recaptcha/src/autoload.php');        

    $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha(SECRET_KEY, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\SocketPost());

    $resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

      if (!$resp->isSuccess()) {
            $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => '<b>Captcha</b> Validation Required!'));
            die($output);               
      } 
}

$toEmail = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mailHeaders = "From: " . $pers_cont. "<" . $email2 . ">\r\n";
$mailContent = "Persoana de contact:". $pers_cont . ">\r\n"."Denumire organizatie: ". $den_org .">\r\n"."Localitate: ". $localitate .">\r\n"."Email: ". $email2 .">\r\n"."Numar Angajati: ". $nr_ang .">\r\n"."Telefon: ".$tlf.">\r\n"."Domeniul de activitate: ". $dom_activ .">\r\n"."Alte informatii pe care le considerati importante: ". $alte .">\r\n"."Numar locatii: ".$iso.">\r\n";
if (mail($toEmail, "O noua oferta completata", $mailContent, $mailHeaders)) {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$pers_cont .', thank you. We will get back to you shortly.'));
    die($output);
} else {
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Unable to send email, please contact administrator'));
    die($output);
     }
    }
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
           var myCheckboxes = [];
            $("input[name='myCheckboxes[]']:checked").each(function () {
                row = $(this).closest("li");
                myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
            });
```

Here you can get value like myCheckboxes=[1,2,3].Pass myCheckboxes to php file using 
 ajax,then in your php file explode it 
    $a= explode(',',myCheckboxes)
 then use for loop

```
for($i=0;i<$a.length;$i++){
your code here with checkbox value as $a[$i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using filter_var,
but

$_POST["myCheckboxes"] is an array (That's how php handles the post names with [])

have a look at:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var-array.php